# Spring JPA Property of @IdClass not found in entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting this error `Property of @IdClass not found in entity com.pandora.label.entity.ArtistLabel: labelId`

These are the tables. they are already created and populated. I can alter the tables but would like to not recreate them. I'm combining the `artist_id` and `label_id` to create a primary key

```
CREATE TABLE label (
    id               BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name             TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    parent_label_id  BIGINT REFERENCES label(id)
)
CREATE INDEX album_uid_idx ON album_label(id);

CREATE TABLE artist_label (
    artist_id         VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    label_id          BIGINT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (artist_id, label_id)
);

CREATE INDEX artist_label_idx ON artist_label(label_id);

ALTER TABLE artist_label ADD CONSTRAINT artist_label_fk FOREIGN KEY (label_id) REFERENCES label(id);
```

these are the Entities

```
@Embeddable
public class ArtistLabelId implements Serializable {
    private String artistId;
    private Long labelId;

    public ArtistLabelId() {
    }

    // setters and getters
}
```

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ArtistLabelId.class)
@Table(name="artist_label",
        indexes = {@Index(name = "artist_idx", columnList = "artist_id")})
public class ArtistLabel {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ArtistLabelId id;

    @Id
    @Column (name = "artist_id")
    private String artistId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("labelId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "label_id")
    private Label label;

    public ArtistLabel() {
    }

    public ArtistLabel(String artistId, Label label) {
        this.artistId = artistId;
        this.label = label;
    }

   // setters and getters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="label")
public class Label {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="label_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "label_generator", sequenceName = "label_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long labelId;

    @Column (name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_label_id")
    private Label parentLabel; //references parent label

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Timestamp createDate;

    @Column(name = "last_modified")
    private Timestamp lastModified;

    public Label(){
        //no-arg constructor for JPA
    }
    
    // setters and getters
```

this is the repository

```
@Repository
public interface ArtistLabelRepository extends CrudRepository<ArtistLabel, ArtistLabelId> {
```

and this is the test. I'm trying to save an artistLabel

```
@Test
    public void testFindByArtistId(){
        Label label1 = new Label("label1", null);
        labelRepository.save(label1);
        ArtistLabel artistLabel1 = new ArtistLabel("artistId1", label1);
        artistLabelRepository.save(artistLabel1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html) you should have the fields in your class and not an `@EmbeddedId`

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ArtistLabelId.class)
@Table(name="artist_label",
        indexes = {@Index(name = "artist_idx", columnList = "artist_id")})
public class ArtistLabel {
    @Id
    private String artistId;
    @Id
    private Long labelId;

    @Id
    @Column (name = "artist_id")
    private String artistId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("labelId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "label_id")
    private Label label;

    public ArtistLabel() {
    }

    public ArtistLabel(String artistId, Label label) {
        this.artistId = artistId;
        this.label = label;
    }

   // setters and getters
}
```

And i think you can get rid of `@Embeddable` on `ArtistLabelId`.

Otherwise you can use `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId` instead of `@IdClass`